# A confusing question about adding an element to a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The following question was discussed in my Discrete Math class, but we couldn't reach a consensus.

**Think of a set as a collection of bins**. Each bin contains exactly one object distinct from all others. While we are allowed to move the objects around between bins, we cannot remove any object, nor can we place two objects into the same bin.

Someone hands us a new object. Can we place that object into a bin, after moving around some of the objects already sitting in bins?

A. Yes, for some sets this works just fine.
B. Sets are not composed of bins and this question makes no sense whatsoever.
C. No, there is no room for another object, all bins are already filled.
D. It depends on the new object.

**I'll try to summarize the general arguments for why each answer is correct or incorrect:**
**A:** A few of us think this is right, because we can insert the new object into the set iff it's not already in it. However, this is similar to answer choice D, which was given to be wrong (see below).
**B:** Many of us shy away from the answer because it "sounds" incorrect, but I personally believe this is the right answer. This is because I disagree with the representation of a set as a collection of bins (each of which contains exactly one object), for the simple reason that the model does not seem to account for adding new bins (and hence does not account for adding new elements).
**C:** Some thought this was correct, if we assume that the number of bins cannot increase (i.e. if we cannot add elements to the set). Some thought this was incorrect for the same reason; because it would mean we can't add any elements to the set at all. **This answer was given to be wrong.**
**D:** Most thought this was correct - if the new object is different from all the objects already in the set, then we can add it, and otherwise we can't. **However, this answer was given to be wrong.** And the fact that this is wrong seems to also imply A is wrong (i.e. the intended answer isn't talking about whether or not the element is already in the set).

**Could someone give a justified answer to this question using concepts from Discrete Math and Set Theory?**

Comment: Was any reason given as to why answer choice D was wrong?

Comment: @ChristopherMiller No feedback was given for D or C. We're really tearing our hair out over this one...

Comment: After reading through a couple of times, I think the answer is $C,$ and that your teacher is trying to demonstrate the pigeonhole principle. However, that answer was given to be wrong. So I guess I am wrong. Hmm...

Comment: Well, I must say I agree with answer B in that "this question makes no sense whatsoever"...

Comment: I don't understand why you would choose to lose the well-defined operations from set theory to create an analogy with "bins" which provides no advantage and makes set operations confusing/non-existent (I don't even know, that's how unclear it is).

Answer (score 2):

This is way too informal to have a good answer, in my opinion. In standard mathematics, given a set $A$ and a set $B$ can you adjoin $B$ to $A$ to get a new set $C$ containing $B$ and all the elements of $A$? Absolutely you can.

With this fantasy of bins with unclear rules about how to manipulate the bins? Who knows.

I’d have to go with ‘answer’ $B$, if anything, but I don’t find this question to be well-posed.

Answer (score 0):

A.

Look up Hilbert’s Hotel. To summarise:

A hotel has infinitely many rooms, numbered 1, 2, 3, and so on.

We start with every room being occupied.

A new guest arrives.

We move the guest in room 1 to room 2, the guest in room 2 to room 3, and so on.

Room 1 is now empty, so the new guest can be accommodated.

——

The same principle can handle $N$ guests. Or even infinitely many guests. It’s fun.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work for a set of finite cardinality, because the strategy of shifting the elements among the bins to make a space assumes that an empty bin exists, no? And the problem specifies that "Each bin contains exactly one object", so this can't happen, right?

Comment: Actually, never mind. The answer choice only states that it works for "some" sets. And by Hilbert's Hotel Paradox, the scenario is valid for any infinite set. So the answer would be A, as you've said in your answer.